# Number of questions regarding forking

Tags: discussion

Unfortunately there are now a high number of questions regarding forking Monero presently. Whilst I think it's right to help hobbyists / students / academics with forking questions, the recent questions being asked do not fit into this bracket. There are many questions from a user who clearly has very little technical background (by the questions he is asking) and I even asked outright in a comment what the reason for forking was, the reply was for a startup with a new coin. I'm all for helping people for various reasons but not to create competition with scam-like forks.

Of course one simple solution is to not answer / comment, but I am wondering whether we should actively remove these types of questions or adjust the remit of this SE to only have questions specifically about Monero with any forking questions purely for academic purposes.

Just want to open the debate here as I'm a little frustrated with the aforementioned type of questions potentially diluting the quality of this SE and potentially helping scammers with forking.

Comment: Can you link to a few examples please?

Comment: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8727/monero-versus-forknote https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8724/how-to-create-a-genesis-block https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8716/make-release-static-win64-error-forking-monero https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8715/exchange-for-monero-fork https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8723/error-first-running-new-monero-fork-build https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8717/pre-mined-monero-fork https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/8648/mining-a-custom-coin-based-on-monero

Comment: Related to this might be discussing whether the tags (with current frequency) hard-fork× 60 and monero-forks× 35 are being used appropriately or if they could be improved

Answer (score 2):

In general, other CryptoNote coins and its related materials are [on-topic](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23731/are-questions-about-other-cryptonote-coins-on-topic). This should include questions about starting coins in general in my opinion.

Of course, these questions may be low-quality even if they are considered on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with [sgp](https://monero.meta.stackexchange.com/users/42/sgp) about what is on topic.

However all questions, including questions relating to starting a new coin should be specific. Overly open ended questions (asking for a complete new developer user guide, which describes all steps involved with creating and launching a new coin) are not appropriate. Overly open ended questions can be closed with the "Unclear What You're Asking?" rationale.